# Traduction de “aimbot"

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

An [*aimbot*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aimbot) is a type of computer game bot used in first-person shooter games to provide varying levels of target acquisition assistance to the player.   How would you say *aimbot* in French?

Comment: Si la très officielle [Commission générale de terminologie et de néologie](http://www.culture.gouv.fr/culture/dglf/terminologie/termino_enrichissement.htm) a besoin d'inspiration, je suggère un _ciblot_.

Answer (score 6):

The word **aimbot** is said as is in French.

Although if you really want to translate it, you could say **une aide à la visée** for the aimbot integrated in most Xbox games.

There are no real translation for the non-legit version, but if you really need an exact translation it would be **un robot viseur**, which is extremely ugly for French. This is the reason we use **aimbot** in French.

Answer (score 4):

In France, everybody says "aimbot" (I am French)

This is a reference:
http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/aimbot.html

Answer (score 3):

In French the term "aimbot" is used, as well as in English.
But if you would like a translation:

```
to aim = viser
```

So, aimbot could be translated by : bot-viseur.

Comment: *Bot* is an english word meaning *robot* (*robot* translating directly to *robot* in French). This means that your "translation" is half French half English.

Comment: I don't know; French is my mother tongue and when we say "un bot" I mean a "software robot" (such as an IRC bot). "Un robot" is generally used to talk about a physical robot, such as NAO, for instance.
But yes, it's a gamer Anglicism, my bad. :)

Comment: Désolé, au Québec nous n'utilisons que rarement ce mot. En fait, on utilise ce mot comme litéralement un mot Anglais dans nos phrases. Comme si on disait *aimbot, wallhack, bunnyhop, etc*. Contrairement aux Français (France), on prononce ces mots avec un accent Anglais. Voilà la raison de ma confusion.

Comment: En effet, l'anglicisme fait vraiment partie de la langue Française en Europe (je suis Belge), avec "week end" et "fin de semaine", par exemple. Et il est vrai que beaucoup ici prononcent les mots Anglais "à la Française"; l'horreur!
Donc tu avais raison. :)
Cheers from Belgium! :D